# Search in database for similar strings

Tags: php, sql

I am creating a search form using php and the sort function `LIKE` in sql to find results from database for a keyword but let's say I have a title "Mr.Robot Season 4 is on Netflix" I want users to be able to find this title by typing "mr robot" and not explicitly typing the fullstop and with LIKE it is not possible. So how can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this seems kinda relevant: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-your-own-search-engine-with-php-and-mysql/32733